# Perl: Using regular expressions with hashes

Tags: regex, perl, hash, bioinformatics

I cannot pinpoint a bug in this submodule I'm writing for analyzing a yeast genome. Help anyone?

The sub should use the hash key as a regular expression to check for a certain pair of capital letters. If we have a match, return the associated value. However, it seems to only match "TT" and return the value 5. I have no idea why it would jump to the TT hash element; everything else seems to be the same between the different elements. I would think it would return each of the values, or none, but it only returns TT.

The full code is here on github: https://github.com/bsima/yeast-TRX

Here is the relevant code (line 159 of script.pl):

```
sub trxScore {

    my ( $dinucleotide ) = @_;

    my %trxScores = (
        qr/(CG)/ => 43,
        qr/(CA)/ => 42,
        qr/(TG)/ => 42,
        qr/(GG)/ => 42,
        qr/(CC)/ => 42,
        qr/(GC)/ => 25,
        qr/(GA)/ => 22,
        qr/(TC)/ => 22,
        qr/(TA)/ => 14,
        qr/(AG)/ =>  9,
        qr/(CT)/ =>  9,
        qr/(AA)/ =>  5,
        qr/(TT)/ =>  5,
        qr/(AC)/ =>  4,
        qr/(GT)/ =>  4,
        qr/(AT)/ =>  0
    );

    foreach my $re (keys %trxScores) {
        if ( match($re,$dinucleotide) ) {
            return $trxScores{$re};
        } else {
            return "null";
        }
    }
}
```

The output is in bayanus-TRXscore.csv:

```
Saccharomyces bayanus
gene,gene pair,position,trx score
...
eYAL001C,TA,23,null
eYAL001C,AT,24,null
eYAL001C,TT,25,5
eYAL001C,TT,26,5
eYAL001C,TT,27,5
eYAL001C,TA,28,null
```

Comment: sidenotes; why `match()` function when only plain regex test is needed, and why `%trxScores` hash when you're iterating over it? (array of array comes to mind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always returning on the first attempted match, which will be the first key in the hash (this is an undefined order in general, but given the exact same hash construction, and same version of Perl, you will tend to access the keys in the same order). If that doesn't match, the code returns "null", and does not attempt another loop. The `return` command will exit the trxScore `sub`, providing value to whatever Perl code called it - a `return` will immediately (and usually cleanly) end all loops and code blocks within a `sub`.

Change your loop as follows:

```
foreach my $re (keys %trxScores) {
    if ( match($re,$dinucleotide) ) {
        return $trxScores{$re};
    }
}
return "null";
```

This will make the `return "null";` only occur after the code has attempted to match with all keys in the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even using regular expressions?  It looks to me like you're just doing string matches.  Also, why do you have a hash?  It looks like you want to match your strings in a certain order, and the hash keys are not kept in any order.

```
$ cat foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Note that this is an ordered array of matcher and scores, not a hash.
my @trxScores = (
    CG => 43,
    CA => 42,
    TG => 42,
    GG => 42,
    CC => 42,
    GC => 25,
    GA => 22,
    TC => 22,
    TA => 14,
    AG =>  9,
    CT =>  9,
    AA =>  5,
    TT =>  5,
    AC =>  4,
    GT =>  4,
    AT =>  0
);

my $dinucleotide = 'GTACTTAAGCTATTGGAGC';

my $found;
while ( my ($matcher,$score) = splice( @trxScores, 0, 2 ) ) {
    print "Trying to match $matcher for a score of $score\n";

    if ( index( $dinucleotide, $matcher ) > -1 ) {
        print "Found $matcher for a score of $score\n";
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ( !$found ) {
    print "Couldn't find any matches\n";
}


$ perl foo.pl
Trying to match CG for a score of 43
Trying to match CA for a score of 42
Trying to match TG for a score of 42
Found TG for a score of 42
```